# How many lightsabers did Anakin lose?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, anakin-skywalker

I have heard that Anakin has a penchant for losing his lightsaber during the Clone Wars. So how many has he been known to have lost over the course of the war?

Answers from both canonicities are welcome.

Answer (score 8):

There's no indication in any canon source that Anakin *permanently* lost his [first](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Anakin_Skywalker%27s_first_lightsaber/Canon) lightsaber, other than when it was [destroyed](https://youtu.be/3HjP1DYi5WQ?t=2m3s). He then had his second lightsaber [taken off him](https://youtu.be/6WzFnZ32i24?t=49s) during his fight with Obi-Wan.

---

The implication is that Anakin lost ***the same one repeatedly*** with *poor, long-suffering Obi-Wan having to go and find them afterwards*. We see several examples of this in [Star Wars: Attack of the Clones](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X9-K1cxj6IQ&feature=youtu.be&t=2m58s) and '[Obi-an and Anakin](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Obi-Wan_%26_Anakin)' #3 & #4

[image]

[image]