# Who's this blue haired character?

Tags: star-wars, character-identification

From the image taken off of [this answer.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/141723/58193)

Who is this character with the blue hair? (The one in the hand drawn red circle)

[image: Blue haired character in comic]

Comment: Any reason I was downvoted, I can't see what is wrong with the question?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I suspect it's because a [simple image search](http://tinyurl.com/simpleimagesearch) would have immediately led you to the comic listed below and from there, an easy find of her name.

Comment: @Valorum I didn't even know you could image search! And if that's the case half of the questions here should be downvoted because a "simple search" would have found the answer. Not arguing to you just saying

Comment: many questions do get downvoted for being too simple. The best ones are the ones that make you go "huh" because you assumed you knew the answer, but it's turns out you didn't, or were wrong.

Comment: Keep in mind that down-votes are pretty typical here, and shouldn't be taken personally.  Many posts have been down voted but you just can't see because they aren't yours.

Comment: The answer is easy to find, but I still gave you a +1 for the hand-drawn circle.

Comment: @Omegacron Well I mean that took a lot of effort

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Her name is [Kolara](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kolara). She first appears in [Obi-Wan and Anakin #1](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Obi-Wan_%26_Anakin)

[image]